# iterate over all values of a pg_conn query in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I have a ruby script where I need to retrieve all values from a database and do stuff with each one retrieved. Currently I am hard coding each retrieval, but this only works if there are 3 values coming back. How can I iterate over this? Below is my code:

```
  require 'pg'
  pg_conn = PGconn.connect(host = "main-pg-db-super.center.com", port = 6433, options = '', tty = '', 
                        dbname = "master_data", login = "user", password = "password")

  all_children = pg_conn.exec("SELECT id FROM pt.tests WHERE parent = '1';") # will return 3 results
  puts all_children[0]['id']
  puts all_children[1]['id']
  puts all_children[2]['id']
```

Comment: You need to learn how to set up your connection. `host = "...", port = ...` isn't how we write Ruby, how we call methods, nor is it doing what you think it is. I'd STRONGLY recommend you use the [Sequel ORM](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) for connecting to a database if you're not using ActiveRecord with Rails as it will make your life a lot easier. If you are truly using Rails, then use ActiveRecord. In either case, using an ORM is easier than using PGconn and makes your code more portable.

Answer (score 9):

```
all_children.each do |child|
  puts child['id']
end
```

Does this not work?